# Error using fopen

Tags: matlab, imshow, imread

I wrote these two lines to read and show an image from a specific location.

```
i = imread('‪C:\Users\m_mal\Desktop\fruit.jpg');
imshow(i);
```

But when I ran the code I got the following error messages.

```
 Error using fopen
 The file name contains characters that are not contained in the filesystem 
 encoding.
 Certain operations may not work as expected.

 Error in imread (line 343)
 [fid,errmsg] = fopen(filename, 'r');

 Error in g (line 1)
 i = imread('?C:\Users\m_mal\Desktop\fruit.jpg');
```

Comment: \ shouldn't be escaped? -> \\

Comment: is there anything wrong in URI?

Comment: replacing the backslashes '\' with the forward slashes '/' didn't help

Comment: Somehow you got the 'left-to-right embedding' character stuck on the front of your string. Copy and paste this string and give it a try: `'C:\Users\m_mal\Desktop\fruit.jpg'`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
 i = imread('?C:\Users\m_mal\Desktop\fruit.jpg');
```

with this:

```
 i = imread('C:\\Users\m_mal\Desktop\fruit.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

The first character of the filename was a non-printing character (possibly a control character).Actually, I had copied and pasted URI from the properties of that image and included some non-printing character.

So, I deleted the URI and wrote it manually. Then the code worked.

You can see this character represented with '?' in the error message:

```
Error in g (line 1)

   i = imread('?C:\Users\m_mal\Desktop\fruit.jpg');
```

That character was not visible but was there.

credit: Matlab community